# Is there a good way to join a stream in spark with a changing table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Our Spark environment:
DataBricks 4.2 (includes Apache Spark 2.3.1, Scala 2.11)

What we try to achieve:
We want to enrich streaming data with some reference data, which is updated regularly. The enrichment is done by joining the stream with the reference data.

What we implemented:
We implemented two spark jobs (jars):
The first one is updating a Spark table `TEST_TABLE` every hour (let’s call it ‘reference data’) by using

```
<dataset>.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("TEST_TABLE")
```

and afterwards calling `spark.catalog.refreshTable("TEST_TABLE")`.

The second job (let’s call it streaming data) is using Spark Structured Streaming to stream reading some data, joining it using `DataFrame.transform()` with table `TEST_TABLE` and writing it to another system.
We are reading the reference data using `spark.read.table(“TEST_TABLE”)` in the function called by `.transform()` so we get the latest values in the table. Unfortunately, the second app crashes every time the first app updates the table. The following message is shown in Log4j output:

```
18/08/23 10:34:40 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 547.0 (TID 5599, 10.139.64.9, executor 0): java.io.FileNotFoundException: dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/code.db/TEST_TABLE/ part-00000-tid-5184425276562097398-25a0e542-41e4-416f-bae8-469899a72c21-36-c000.snappy.parquet

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readFile(FileScanRDD.scala:203)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$createNextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:377)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$prepareNextFile$1.apply(FileScanRDD.scala:295)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$prepareNextFile$1.apply(FileScanRDD.scala:291)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748
```

We also tried to invalidate the cache before we read the table but that decreased the performance and the app crashed nevertheless.
We suspect the root course is the lazy evaluation of the reference dataset (which still ‘points’ to the old data, which is not present anymore).

Do you have any suggestions what we could do to prevent this problem or what the best approach to join a stream with dynamic reference data is?

Comment: If you dot cache it should go back to source. How big is that refresh data?

Comment: do not cache   I meant to say

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Join to the reference data; do not cache it, this ensures you go to source. Look for latest version data which is signified by a primary key + a counter, where this counter closest to or equal to a counter you maintain in Streaming application. Every hour write, append all the ref data still current, again but with incremented counter; i.e. a new version. Use parquet here.

Comment: Thank you! :) Instead of an counter we are using timestamps now, but in general we are using your solution. Our main problem was the overwriting instead of appending of data in the reference data tables.

Comment: I just kept it simpler based on not knowing your situation explicitly.

Comment: @BdLearner  As I wrote the answer I should know. It is for versioning in a non mutable environment, may not apply to your situation wuth Cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of joining the table and stream. You can take advantage of a new feature available in spark 2.3.1 i.e joining of two streams data.
Create a stream instead of a table with the watermark.

```
Watermarks: Watermarking in Structured Streaming is a way to limit state in all 
stateful streaming operations by specifying how much late data to consider. 
Specifically, a watermark is a moving threshold in event-time that trails behind the 
maximum event-time seen by the query in the processed data. The trailing gap (aka 
watermark delay) defines how long should the engine wait for late data to arrive and 
is specified in the query using withWatermark.
```

[Refer databricks blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/08/event-time-aggregation-watermarking-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html)

Comment: Regarding water marks , let’s say I have transaction stream and another stream which has Country try codes now if country code changes if I use update state by key I will have latest code for the key so I can join latest transactions stream latest key , how watermarks helps me with dimension data which has country codes so do you I have keep watermark for indefinite time on dimension table ? In my case countrycode changes once a week.